# Target a specific element on the page

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm somewhat of a newbie.

I'm working in Sharepoint and I'm trying to target just the lower third of the page that has the following div structure:

```
<div id ="mainwrapper">
  <div id ="lowercontainer">
    <div class ="centercolumn">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is the rule that I want to change it's text color:

```
.ms-pb,
.ms-pb-selected, 
.ms-vb, 
.ms-vb-tall, 
.ms-vb-user, 
.ms-vb2
```

I don't want to change it on the entire page, just the part in the div for the lower container, center column.

So I've tried the following:

```
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-pb, 
.ms-pb-selected, 
.ms-vb, 
.ms-vb-tall, 
.ms-vb-user, 
.ms-vb2 
{color:red;}
```

But it changes it in the entire page - how can I just target only the this particular rule (`.ms-pb, .ms-pb-selected, .ms-vb, .ms-vb-tall, .ms-vb-user, .ms-vb2`) That's in the lower container, center column?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the selectors for your divs to all the selectors you want to override, not just the first one.

Ex:

```
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-pb, 
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-pb-selected, 
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb, 
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb-tall, 
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb-user, 
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb2 {
    color:red;
}
```

This will target the `.ms-pb, 
.ms-pb-selected, .ms-vb, .ms-vb-tall, .ms-vb-user, .ms-vb2`  classes only within `#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn`

Comment: somewhat complex.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `class` in `css` and put your changes in it then add this new `class` to the `div` elements that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current selector is that it targets **every** element after the comma, not taking into consideration the previous elements. That is to say, the following **independent** selectors are all targetted:

```
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-pb
.ms-pb-selected
.ms-vb
.ms-vb-tall
.ms-vb-user
.ms-vb2
```

With the above, the `.ms-vb` classes will be targetted even if they don't come under the `#mainwrapper` element.

When using commas in CSS selectors, you need to specify the prefix **each time**, as:

```
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-pb,
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-pb-selected,
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb,
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb-tall,
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb-user,
#mainwrapper #lowercontainer .centercolumn .ms-vb2 {
  color: red;
}
```

Note that adding in extra targets increases the level of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. While the above **should** work for you, you can always increase specificity if you need to override rules. A good selector in this case would be the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**, which targets **direct** children:

```
#mainwrapper > #lowercontainer > .centercolumn > .ms-pb,
#mainwrapper > #lowercontainer > .centercolumn > .ms-pb-selected,
#mainwrapper > #lowercontainer > .centercolumn > .ms-vb,
#mainwrapper > #lowercontainer > .centercolumn > .ms-vb-tall,
#mainwrapper > #lowercontainer > .centercolumn > .ms-vb-user,
#mainwrapper > #lowercontainer > .centercolumn > .ms-vb2 {
  color: red;
}
```

In the above, each of the `.ms` elements would need to come directly under the `.centercolumn` class, directly under `#lowercontainer`, which is in itself directly under `#mainwrapper`.

This should prevent erroneous elements from being selected.

Hope this helps! :)